# Hyper-V VM Replication: Workable for a production SQL Server VM?

Tags: windows, hyper-v

We currently use VMWare ESX 5.5, and run mostly Win VMs (a few linux). The biggest VM is the production SQL Server (SQL Server 2014, std ed).

We are evaluating DR options, and it appears life is a lot simpler on hyper-v, which has native VM replication. Yes, we know about SAN replication and all the other nice music. But it looks totally simpler to do it at the hypervisor level.

So, we are considering migrating from VMWare to hyper-v.

The question is: is hyper-v replication a solid option for SQL Server itself?

Our idea is to let hyper-v do all the work, and to have the production SQL Server push its tlogs to cloud storage. So, if we need to "catch up" the VM replica prior to bringing it on line, we can apply logs.

SQL Server DB is 0.5-1.0 TB

Comment: Yes, take a look here for supported configurations https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/956893

Comment: Hyper-V Replica is a poor man's failover clustering. If you have a second Hyper-V host of which you can make a Replica target, you might as well go the rest of the way and just create a Hyper-V Failover Cluster.

Comment: "Hyper-V Replica is a poor man's failover clustering" Right! Properly configured Hyper-V cluster just assumes some physical or virtual shared storage for CSV.

Comment: @joeqwerty OK, so it is poor man's failover clustering... Is it appro for a busy SQL server?  Will the DB stay in one piece?

Comment: Is it appropriate for a SQL Server? My opinion is that it isn't the best, nor a very good solution for SQL Server. You'd be better off using SQL's own HA features rather than using Hyper-V Replica. If you do use Hyper-V Replica make sure to follow this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956893 **(SQL Server on Hyper-V Replica is supported provided the EnableWriteOrderPreservationAcrossDisks flag is set)**

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned above, Hyper-V replica is not the best choice to get a properly working and highly available MS SQL server. You have to stick with MS SQL own HA options which are either SQL Server Always On Availability Groups feature https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx, that is now available with a standard license or SQL Server Failover Cluster Instances that in case need some shared storage between your hosts. In order to run MS SQL Failover Cluster Instances that are proven to be more reliable, you will need to install MS Failover Cluster role. Shared storage can be provided by a software-define storage solution like Starwind https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free for example, which is free for use in your scenario.

In both cases, it is not mandatory to migrate to Hyper-V, since above-mentioned configurations can be made on top of existing ESX infrastructure.